# Ontological non-taxonomic relationship - Gold Standard evaluation ? - Genia ontology

Tags: nlp, ontology, evaluation, relationships, corpus

I am working on extraction of non-taxonomic relationships between concepts in domain ontology learning. There is not exist a corpus and corresponding ontology for evaluation propose. In previews related works, in some work, use of some Gold standards such Genia, Tourism (loneyPlanet), Family law, ... ; but not exist this domain corpus and ontology on the web. Just exist Genia domain that is without reference non-taxonomic relationships. Other reference ontology such Cancer Chemoprevention (CANCO) are without having a corpus for learning.

There is exist some corpus and ontology for Gold standard evaluation of this ontological relationships?

Comment: What type of "ontological relationships" you have in mind?

Comment: As said in question, Non-taxonomic relationships between domain concepts (class in owl), means any relationships except is-a (taxonomic) relations.

Comment: Have you considered using Freebase?